# Deleting spaces between <li> in a flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

This is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 30px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.column_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/* Version Two */

#two ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- Version One -->

<div class="column">
  <div class="column_content">
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Version Two -->

<div class="column">
  <div class="column_content" id="two">
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
      <li>Fourth</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to use `display: flex;`, so Version One is the version I would like to work with. But there are spaces between the text blocks. In Version Two, you can see how it would look like without these spaces.

How is it possible to remove them, but keeping all other settings?

Thanks!

Comment: it's not completely clear to me what you want? Can you please change up your question a bit?

Comment: you are not working with flexbox at all. There is no display:flex in your code